# Is there any way to detect changes in Console (Devtools)?

Tags: javascript, console, devtools

im looking for answers on my question. And i can't find any.
So as example:

```
this.connect = false;

if (this.connect) {
  alert('CONNECTED');
}
```

If i change `this.connect = true` in my devtools -> console. It should alert message 'CONNECTED'.

Is there any way to do that? Will be awesome to get this to work!

Comment: you could use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) I guess in a round about way - but, only if `this` is `window`, becuase `this` in the console is `window`

Comment: Could you make any example? I never use Proxy.

Comment: actually, the answer by jns doesn't use proxy, and is far easier to understand for a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Theres no need for a Proxy. Just use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/defineProperty) to define a get/set method for the connected property of the window.

Hey have a look at this snippet - guess this is a good way to start with.

```js
// We are using a property _connected to store the value of the connected property
let _connected = false;

// We are defining a property with the name 'connected' on the this (this = globalThis = window => console dev tool)
Object.defineProperty(this, 'connected', {
  get: () => _connected,
  set: (value) => {
    _connected = value;
    console.log(`Setting 'connected' to: ${value}`);
  }
});

// Try using this.connected = $val inside your console.
this.connected = true;
this.connected = false;
this.connected = "foo";
```

---

Using a Proxy like *@Jaromanda X* suggested is also possible but I guess it is not be best solution because overwriting the window/this/globalThis - scope seems to be impossible:

```js
const _this = new Proxy(window, {
  set: (target, key, value) => {
      if (key === "connected")
        console.log(`Setting 'connected' to set to ${value}`);
      target[key] = value;
      return true;
  }
});

_this.connected = true;
_this.connected = false;
_this.connected = "foo";
```

Comment: I think `this` should be replaced with `globalThis` for cross-platform support.

Comment: Yes that was the answer. I never used defineProperty! I need to look more in this topic! Thank you for your answer. This is it! Love you <3